# Button action do vb .net não funciona

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Quero fazer uma simples ação quando um botão for clicado porém nada acontece.

Arquivo aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderNormal" runat="server">
    <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" ID="Teste" />
</asp:Content>
```

Arquivo aspx.vb

```
Private Sub Teste_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Teste.Click
        Teste.Text = "asdasd"
End Sub
```

Nesse caso não acontece nada quando o botão é clicado.
Caso eu coloque um evento onclick no botão acontece esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não está faltando no botão `OnClick="Teste_Click"`?

Comment: Da um erro= 'Teste_click' is not a member  of "web_administrator_configuracoes_usuario_cadastrosetor.aspx"

Comment: estranho, tem certeza que esse botão está na *"Arquivo.aspx"*? Está aparecendo erro de outra página, *"cadastrosetor.aspx"*

Comment: Infelizmente sim, na verdade o código é da tela cadastrosetor.aspx não tenho ideia do que possa ser já que os outros botões do sistema funcionam normalmente.

Comment: *"Infelizmente sim, na verdade o código é da tela cadastrosetor.aspx"* não entendi bem, ficou confuso isso. Na própria página onde está o botão, no arquivo `.aspx` abra uma tag `<script runat="server">` e dentro copie o método `Private Sub Teste_Click` e veja se funciona

Comment: Fiz desse modo e funcionou, tem alguma ideia do porque disso? Ah muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Tenta dar um "Rebuild Web Site" na aplicação...

Comment: Onde fica essa opção?

Comment: Fica no Visual Studio, abra o seu projeto, clique no menu Build => Rebuild Web Site.